# C# Taskbar Progressbar doesn't work right with Invoke

Tags: c#, invoke

As I was told yesterday, the taskbar progressbar can be accessed by just using Invoke and updating the value there. That works great, but with one problem:

When the window of my application is focused, the following code produces the output that I want, which is the value of *currentTaskbarValue*. But as soon as I switch to e.g. Firefox while the application is running, I get the Exception that says: "*Taskbar Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*"

And as soon as I focus the application again, the current value is printed to the debugging console.

```
private static void reportTaskbarProgress()
{
    try
    {
        Filtertest.MainForm.ActiveForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
        {taskbar.SetProgressValue(currentTaskbarValue, maximumTaskbarValue);});

        Debug.WriteLine("" + currentTaskbarValue);

        currentTaskbarValue ++;
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Taskbar Exception: " + exception.Message);
    }
}
```

It's actually not a problem, because the application is still running and producing the right results, but for progress reporting it's kind of an issue, because the taskbar never reaches 100% and therefore uses its permission to reside in my application.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The code above resides in a different class and doesn't have access to all components on the MainForm (Just one button)!

Comment: Why are you using the ActiveForm to invoke the delegate? I'm not sure but this property could be null if another application has the focus. *Any* control will be sufficient to invoke a delegate on the UI thread.

Comment: Maybe because there is no active form. Try calling `Invoke` of `taskbar` instead.

Comment: @tia Could you tell me what that code would look like? I don't know where you mean I should write that.

Comment: Like this: `taskbar.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { taskbar.SetProgressValue(currentTaskbarValue, maximumTaskbarValue); });`

Comment: @groverboy Ok, thanks. But _taskbar_ seems to have no Invoke() method. It's an object of the TaskbarManager class, if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => taskbar.SetProgressValue(currentTaskbarValue, maximumTaskbarValue)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is still one problem: The application is running and printing the current progressbar value, but the progressbar doesn't do anything. It's neither green or red or anything, it's just normal.

Comment: Ok, I found the mistake: The progress was shown in the part of the taskbar of a messagebox that opened for testing purposes and as soon as I closed it the progressbar was gone. I removed that messagebox now and it works. Thanks!